# Resize external website content to fit iFrame width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I have a webpage with 2 iFrames in it. Both of them are with fixed width and height. I am loading external websites inside them. How can I resize those external websites width to fit with the iFrame (like mobile browsers does by changing viewport)?

Comment: That is not possible IMHO [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298210/how-to-embed-a-resized-website-throught-an-iframe).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

What you can do is set specific width and height to your iframe (for example these could be equal to your window dimensions) and then applying a scale transformation to it. The scale value will be the ratio between your window width and the dimension you wanted to set to your iframe.

E.g.

```
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
```

Comment: true, but it depends on your definition of cross-browser solution. AFAIK it should work in IE>8

Comment: But the iframe dimension is also scaled, not only content's dimension.

Comment: worked like magic! to keep the iframe in place i also added 
iframe{
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

Comment: @DotNetFan Play with the iframe width and height until the scrollbar[s] go away, then scale the whole thing to the desired size.

Answer (score 3):

Tip for 1 website resizing the height. But you can change to 2 websites.

Here is my code to resize an iframe with an external website. You need insert a code into the parent (with iframe code) page and in the external website as well, so, this won't work with you don't have access to edit the external website.

- local (iframe) page: just insert a code snippet
- remote (external) page: you need a "body onload" and a "div" that holds all contents. And body needs to be styled to "margin:0"

Local:

```
<IFRAME STYLE="width:100%;height:1px" SRC="http://www.remote-site.com/" FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDER="0" SCROLLING="no" ID="estframe"></IFRAME>

<SCRIPT>
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  if (e.data.substring(0,3)=='frm') document.getElementById('estframe').style.height = e.data.substring(3) + 'px';
},false);
</SCRIPT>
```

You need this "frm" prefix to avoid problems with other embeded codes like Twitter or Facebook plugins. If you have a plain page, you can remove the "if" and the "frm" prefix on both pages (script and onload).

Remote:

You need jQuery to accomplish about "real" page height. I cannot realize how to do with pure JavaScript since you'll have problem when resize the height down (higher to lower height) using body.scrollHeight or related. For some reason, it will return always the biggest height (pre-redimensioned).

```
<BODY onload="parent.postMessage('frm'+$('#master').height(),'*')" STYLE="margin:0">
<SCRIPT SRC="path-to-jquery/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<DIV ID="master">
your content
</DIV>
```

So, parent page (iframe) has a 1px default height. The script inserts a "wait for message/event" from the iframe. When a message (post message) is received and the first 3 chars are "frm" (to avoid the mentioned problem), will get the number from 4th position and set the iframe height (style), including 'px' unit.

The external site (loaded in the iframe) will "send a message" to the parent (opener) with the "frm" and the height of the main div (in this case id "master"). The "*" in postmessage means "any source".

Hope this helps. Sorry for my english.