# Resize web page into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my project i load an external web page into a div with small dimension (250x295) with this function:

```
 <div> 
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com" width="250px" height="295px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object></div>
```

the problem is that in div i see just the 250x295 portion of page, need scroll to view all data.
Is possible resize entire page related at the div dimension? (like a "preview")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe using some thumbnail API? ie screenshot of a page.

Comment: may be this could help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382473/resize-external-website-content-to-fit-iframe-width

Comment: @LouisXIV: thumbnails api is used to resize the image and still retain the picture quality, here its a web page not a image, so it wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with CSS3 2d transforms' `scale()` method:

```
div {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    -o-transform: scale(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}
```

Comment: Good call, that was my first thought too.

Answer (score 1):

You arrange div's in this way make it look like preview, hope it will help.

```
<div style="border:5px ridge blue;display:inline-block;width:250px; height:295px;">
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:inherit; " >     

<object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com"  
style="overflow:hidden;  height:inherit; position:relative; width:inherit;">    
</object> 

</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qwHFC/)