# How would I resize this iFrame for my website?

Tags: iframe

I would like to get it to around 150 x 150 if possible.

```
<!-- Begin NOAA Weather Radio Live Gadget-->
<center>
<iframe name="NOAA Weather Radio Live Gadget" src="http://broadcast-weather.net/live_noaa_weather_n.html" allowTransparency="true" width="290" height="250" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
</iframe><br>
<a href="http://broadcast-weather.net/noaa.html">NOAA Weather Radio Live</a></center>
<!-- End NOAA Weather Radio Live Gadget-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="height: 150px; width: 150px" to your iframe

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it is not resizing. The iFrame is from another website that I want to use on mine. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add it like this?: <iframe blahblah style="height: 150px; width: 150px">

Comment: Well there you go, adjust to your needs

Comment: Yea, but I need it smaller than the standard size in the code above. When I say it cuts the widget in half, I literally mean it chops it right down the middle and the right half is gone...

Comment: I think this might help you then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382473/resize-external-website-content-to-fit-iframe-width