# How can I make an html page automatically fit mobile device screens?

Tags: html, forms, iframe, mobile, formidable

I am putting a Formidable Form on an html page by using an `<iframe>`, but I'd like it to be full screen on a mobile device. So far I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <style>
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch);

  body {
  background-color: #f3eedd;
  width: 750px;
  overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #c13e18;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h2>Book Supheroes Unite</h2>
</div>
<div id="form">
<iframe src="http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frm_forms_preview&form=sbyrt02
" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:280px;height:535px;"></iframe></div>
</html>
```

I believe it has something to do with viewports? However, I'm not entirely sure on this!

Comment: Let me know if the meta tag I provided solves your problem.

Comment: Hey @Chris the meta works, however I'm having a tough time with the iframe... That doesn't seem to want to auto scale to fit the device screen!

Comment: Hmmmm, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382473/resize-external-website-content-to-fit-iframe-width) That seems to handle the new issue.

Comment: Essentially you have defined the width and height already. So, I'd be willing to bet that no matter what, your Iframe is 280px by 535px?

Comment: Thanks @Chris I'm not sure why but this doesn't seem to be 100% correct. Check it out http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-content/uploads/book-super.html if you get a spare minute.

Comment: Also this is what I'm trying to insert with the iframe http://challenge-the-box.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frm_forms_preview&form=sbyrt02

Comment: Can you try it with no width or height attribute? I am playing with your code now. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This meta tag allows you to target mobile devices and sets the width to the screen size.

Documentation provided [here!](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Also consider migrating to bootstrap a CSS framework for Responsive web design! [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use a library like bootstrap to acheive this adding something like this to your head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) allows you to create dynamic grids with your content regardless of the device size. You simply create divs inside a larger container for example the fluid container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just note you do not need bootstrap to implement that meta tag.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `media queries` !
looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  //your css to make it full screen
}
```