# Xamarin Forms: Pinch zooming and scroll is not working for WebView content

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using `WebView` for showing Flip snack Book and Games on the UI.

Facing 2 issues when showing content:

1. Pinch zooming is not working on the Android platform when showing books.
2. Not able to scroll and view the content when showing games on all platforms.

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch) blog for pinch zooming. Also when showing the games I can't scroll to right and view the content. I have created a sample [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hcGThokJGrnsuhVZ-xUsIQ9uoUOqy2RK/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Note: Currently, the book link is set as the source value. Uncomment the game source line on MainPage.xaml.cs to check the game scroll issue.

**Update 1:**

I have added the custom webview from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5205), but the webview scroll is not working on android(also not working on ios).

Also added the webview zoom controls as per this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/webview-zoom-controls), it is also not working on android.

**My XF version is 4.8.0.1269**

Comment: A webview contains a native platform (e.g. Android) browser window. You don't use normal Xamarin Forms pinch zoom, instead you use [Android-specific WebView Zoom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/webview-zoom-controls).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried this but zooming is not working on android

Comment: I did reproduce the two problem , I'm afraid it can be solved with code in xamarin .It will be easier to manipulate the html to make it automatically fit mobile device and enable zoom feature rather than seeking workaround on mobile, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782454/how-can-i-make-an-html-page-automatically-fit-mobile-device-screens .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the pinch zooming and scrolling are working for some other URLs.

The issue is only with my URL, concluded that my URLs has responsive issues.