# HTML CSS - How to fit the iframe content to the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, frames

I have an issue when I change the size of the frame frame gets bigger but not the content. I need to fit the content inside the Iframe to the frame.

My css is:

```
#IDNAME { 
  -moz-transform: scale(0.90, 0.90); 
  -moz-transform-origin: 
  top left; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: my code is,<style>
  #IDNAME {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.90, 0.90); 
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  }
</style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the width and height of the iframe in order for it to scale the content. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382473/resize-external-website-content-to-fit-iframe-width).

```
#IDNAME { 
  -moz-transform: scale(0.90, 0.90); 
  -moz-transform-origin: 
  top left; 
  width: 1024px;
  height: 576px;
}
```