# Resize Iframe content according to Iframe Width/Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How do I resize a Iframe's contents to fill the width/height of the Iframe?

I've changed the width and height of the Iframe to make it bigger, however the content is not scaling with it which leaves a bunch of whitespace (It's like the content is absolutely positioned at the top left of the Iframe).

```html
<iframe width="500px" height="300px" frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" src="someContent">
</iframe>
```

Why doesn't the Iframe's content scale when you set an Iframe's width/height?

Comment: What do you mean by scale? Do you mean you'd like to zoom the content?

Comment: I would like the content to fit the size of the Iframe's new dimensions. The content seems to be a fixed size so when I increase the width/height of the Iframe, the content's size does not change.

Comment: do you have control over the iframe content? is it your website that you can edit?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example (e.g. in a snippet), so the community can help you better?

Comment: @AlexGru <iframe width="500px" height="300px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="someContent"></iframe>. Say the content fits the width and height mentioned in the Iframe. If I increase the iFrame size to say 1000px/600px, the content stays the same size, but the frame increases. I would like the content's size to increase to fill the new Iframe's dimensions.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think I have control. I was thinking more in terms of the content being a chart from an Excel spreadsheet or a video from YouTube

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the content of the iframe (i.e. you cannot edit the source), you could try to scale the iframe, like this:

```html
<iframe width="500px" height="300px" frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" src="someContent" 
  style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);">
</iframe>
```

You should experiment with `height`, `width` and the scale value to achieve your desired result.

Also see: [Resize external website content to fit iFrame width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382473/resize-external-website-content-to-fit-iframe-width/11382661#11382661)

Comment: With this method the width and height of the Iframe seem to be changing but not the size of the content. The content i'm testing is a chart from an Excel spreadsheet if that makes any difference. (used onedrive to embed a chart in a webpage via Iframe)

Comment: Have you experimented with different combinations of `width`, `height` and `scale`?

Comment: I was experimenting with the scale as I would like the IFrame to be a specific size

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have any other options than that, since you cannot edit the styles of the external content in the iframe.