# show all the target site in small frame (html)

Tags: html, frame, frameset

My friend needs a site to monitor some other sites online in a page.
I use frame  to make the page for him. but I have a problem!
my frames are 300*600 and I want to show all the target site or 100%width and 70% height in my small frame!
what should I do?
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: look - when you make a small frame in html , It will just show a small part of target site ! I want to show the whole page in a small frame!

Comment: srry my English is not good

Comment: So you want to shrink or scale down a normal page for example stackoverflow.com to fit in a frame that is 300x600 without distorting. Just the same thing but smaller?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has prevsiously been adressed a few times on SO. 
For example in: 
[Resize external website content to fit iFrame width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11382661/605112.)
and 
[How to embed a resized website throught an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298210/how-to-embed-a-resized-website-throught-an-iframe/15506367#15506367)

The answer is basically to set the iframe to desired width and height. The you  use CSS to scale it. Since this uses a webkit or mozilla function it may not work in all browsers.

```
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
```